# SQL empty strings and text formatting

Tags: sql, text-formatting

I am trying to do some text formatting with sql (MS SQL server 2008). I have three variables which are either going to return empty strings or some sort of text, they will never be null. I would like the display the text in the following way:
    @Var1='A' @Var2='B' @Var3='C' ==> A, B, C
    @Var1='A' @Var2='' @Var3='C' ==> A, C
    @Var1='' @Var2='B' @Var3='C' ==> B, C
    @Var1='' @Var2='' @Var3='C' ==> C
    .
    .
    .
    @Var1='' @Var2='' @Var3='' ==>
    etc

Here is a simplified version of what I have...

```
DECLARE @Var1 NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Var2 NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Var3 NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Var1 = 'A'
SET @Var2 = 'B'
SET @Var3 = 'C'
SELECT 
ISNULL(NULLIF(@Var1,''), '') 
    + 
        CASE
            WHEN NULLIF(@Var1,'') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(@Var2,'') IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' ELSE '' 
        END 
    +
ISNULL(NULLIF(@Var2,''),'')
    +
        CASE
            WHEN NULLIF(@Var2,'') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(@Var3,'') IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' ELSE '' 
        END 
    +
ISNULL(NULLIF(@Var3,''),'')
```

I feel like I am missing some important details. Let me know if there is any clarification needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select  case 
        when str is null then ''
        else left(str, len(str)-1) -- Remove last comma
        end
from    (
        select  case when len(@Var1) > 0 then @Var1 + ', ' else '' end + 
                case when len(@Var2) > 0 then @Var2 + ', ' else '' end + 
                case when len(@Var3) > 0 then @Var3 + ', ' else '' end as str
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Or with a `reverse` trick to avoid the subquery:

```
select  reverse(stuff(reverse(
        case when len(@Var1) > 0 then @Var1 + ', ' else '' end +
        case when len(@Var2) > 0 then @Var2 + ', ' else '' end +
        case when len(@Var3) > 0 then @Var3 + ', ' else '' end
        ), 1, 2, ''));
```

The key point here is that SQL Server is not very good at text formatting :)  You're infinitely better off in a client side language like C#.

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/2114/0)

Comment: Remember to remove the final comma.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have that option available because the background is that a webservice is calling a stored procedured and converting what it returned to xml, there is no place to use any client side language.

Comment: @user1401635 - And what is consuming the XML?  Could that deal with three items instead of one?  `<var1>xxx</var1><var2></var2></var3>yyy</var3>`?

Comment: The xml is being consumed by a DevEx report. I am binding the output of theses variables into one string and putting them in a node that is bound to a textbox in a report.

Comment: This answer doesnt quite work. For example, if I have `@Var1 = 'A' @Var2 = '' and @Var 3 = 'C'` I get A, , C. Too many commas

Comment: I assumed `@Var2` would be `null`, not `''`.  Answer updated to work for both cases.